# C++0x library that implements move for fstreams

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, move-semantics, move-constructor

After finding the answer to [How to return an fstream (C++0x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825851/how-to-return-an-fstream-c0x), I was now wondering if there is a current c++0x library that implements move (or even swap) for fstreams (as [gcc (27.9)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) does not). I'd prefer if it was free also.

Or is there any other way return to fstreams from functions by value?

I've tried compiling [libcxx](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) but it seems very linux/mac specific, and I need it to run on Solaris also, which it wouldn't compile on.

I can work around this issue (return by reference for example), but I thought I'd ask this just in case there was a solution that doesn't involve modifying the calling code.

Comment: The C++ Standard Library that ships with Visual C++ 2010 has moveable streams.

Comment: Thank you for attempting libcxx.  There is interest in porting it but such work is in the early stages.  Volunteers to port welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Dinkumware](http://dinkumware.com/) sells a version of the C++ Standard Library with movable streams, but be sure to check it first.

Comment: Apparently (from the comments) James McNellis has checked it out and agrees with you.