# Creating objects runtime

Tags: c++

i want to create `std::ifstream` object at runtime as i create new thread ,

```
ifstream& 
getMultiDataReaderStream()
{
      ifstream ifs;
        ifs.open(m_dataReaderFileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
    return ifs;
}

void
runThread(void *lpData)
{
      ifstream& ifs1 = storeManager.getMultiDataReaderStream();
      // code for reading while EOF
      ifs1.close();
}
```

But , I am getting segmentation Fault is something wrong in above code....

Comment: you're returning a reference to an object that gets destroyed after the function getMultiDataReaderStream is done.  This reference gets used, which causes a seg fault.

Comment: OK..is any other way to do this...

Comment: there are several ways to solve this.  1.  pass a reference to the object in, then call open.  2.  allocate using new and return a pointer.  2a.  use solution 2 with smart pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment.

There are many ways to fix this.  One is this:

```
void getMultiDataReaderStream(ifstream& ifs)
{
    ifs.open(m_dataReaderFileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
}

void
runThread(void *lpData)
{
      ifstream ifs1;
      getMultiDataReaderStream(ifs1);
      // code for reading while EOF
      ifs1.close();
}
```

Another is this:
   (don't use this, this works, but it's sloppy)

```
ifstream* getMultiDataReaderStream()
{
    ifstream* ifs = new ifstream(m_dataReaderFileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
    return ifs;
}

void
runThread(void *lpData)
{
      ifstream* ifs1 = getMultiDataReaderStream();
      // code for reading while EOF
      ifs1->close();
      delete ifs1;
}
```

And then with smart ptr:

```
shared_ptr<ifstream> getMultiDataReaderStream()
{
    shared_ptr<ifstream> ifs = shared_ptr<ifstream>(new ifstream(m_dataReaderFileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary));
    return ifs;
}

void
runThread(void *lpData)
{
      shared_ptr<ifstream> ifs1 = getMultiDataReaderStream();
      // code for reading while EOF
      ifs1->close();
}
```

I am sure there are other ways...

Comment: Consider using `std::unique_ptr` over `std::shared_ptr` here, as there is no attested need for shared ownership.

Answer (score 1):

According to this: [Is std::ofstream movable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066691/is-stdofstream-movable)

both `ifstream` and `ofstream` **should be movable**, so you should be able to simply "just return it". But, many compilers does not have their stdlibs adapted to C'11 properly. For instance, I've just tried it at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ which seems to have g++ 4.8 and I still cannot move/return any fstream - compiler still insists on using nonexistent copy-constructor instead of move ctor.

This was a known issue that GCC hadn't implemented movability in the streams part. Sorry, I don't know anything more. You'll need to stick with the workarounds until c'11 support gets better.

Answer (score 0):

You should never return a reference (or a pointer) to a local object from a function. In this case, `getMultiDataReaderStream()` is returning a reference to an object (`ifs`) that is destroyed as soon as you leave the function. So using it is invalid and leads to undefined behaviour. For instance, a segmentation fault.