# Why can't I move std::ofstream?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, fstream

Looking at previous answers on SO, it seems that while `std::ostream` is not be movable, `std::ofstream` should be. However, this code

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs;
    std::ofstream ofs2{std::move(ofs)};
}
```

does not seem to compile in any version of gcc or clang I tried (with either --std=c++11 or --std=c++14). The compiler error varies somewhat, but here's what I get for gcc 4.9.0

```
6 : error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_ofstream::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream&)'
```

Is this the expected behavior, according to the standard?

Note that a very similar question was asked before ( [Is std::ofstream movable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7066691/1027857) ) but seems the standard has changed since then ( as detailed in 
[Why can't std::ostream be moved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774587/why-cant-stdostream-be-moved) ) rendering those answers outdated. Certainly, none of those answers explains why the code above does not compile.

Came across this issue when trying to use containers of `ofstream`, which does not work because of the above.

Comment: compiles fine with Clang 3.4.1 on freebsd using --std=c++11.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the standard

> 27.9.1.11 basic_ofstream constructors

or, its more "readable" version http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream , `std::basic_ostream<>` has a move constructor, so the code should compile.

clang++ 3.5 compiles it with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++1y`. Also gcc5 compiles it, so probably it is not implemented in libstdc++ for gcc < 5

Interestingly, the lack of move semantics is not mentioned on gcc's stdlibc++ implementation https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2014

See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54316 for a bug report, thanks to @BoBTFish for pointing out. It is confirmed that the issue was fixed in gcc5.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54316 Note that at the top it only mentions `stringstream`, but further down it becomes clear this also applies to `ofstream`. And the bottom entry is "Fixed for GCC 5".

Comment: Well, that seems pretty definitive. Had not tried gcc5, but did try clang 3.5 using http://gcc.godbolt.org/ and it did not work, guess it's an issue with that site. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @toth just glancing at your code in the link, I see that you are using `std::is_lvalue_reference_v`. AFAIK, there is no such `using` in C++11/14, so you have to use `std::is_value_reference<U>::value`. I know, they should have defined it, similar to the type traits `_t` (from `<>::type`)