# How do deal with noncopyable members in conjunction with named constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11

**Background**

I have a chunk of code with the following characteristics:

1. `IO` class which is non-copyable due to a `std::ifstream` member
2. `Foo` class which has a NamedConstructor, that likes to call a copy constructor

**Question**

*Is there a pattern I can use where I keep the NamedConstructor in Foo (or something equivalent), but I still can insert non-copyable members into Foo?*

I welcome C++11 features/solutions.

**Test Code**

```
#include <fstream>

class IO
{
        std::ifstream  m_ifs;  // due to this instance, IO is not copyable
};

// #define NEXT_LINE_REQUIRES_IO_MC

class Foo
{
#ifdef NEXT_LINE_REQUIRES_IO_MC
        IO  m_io;
#endif

public:
        static Foo NamedConstructor() {
                return Foo();
        }
private:
        Foo() { }
};

int
main( int argv, char* argc[] )
{
        Foo f = Foo::NamedConstructor();
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using some smart pointer?

Comment: What you have there should compile fine in C++11, because `ifstream` is moveable, and therefore `IO` should be too.  However, I just tested it with MinGW (gcc 4.8), and it apparently does not compile, complaining about a deleted move constructor. If you have the same problem, this is a bug.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley crap - I think you are right, according to this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4846927/975129 fwiw, I am using gcc 4.7.3

Comment: @kfmfe04: In the meantime, you should probably go with Basile's suggestion, and use `unique_ptr<ifstream>`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley ty, I will try that.  btw, the compiler-generated move constructor should give me the correct behavior in my snippet above, right?  Since the rhs of the NamedConstructor disappears anyways (maybe even through RVO), I assume I am safe.  (I haven't played with move constructors at all...)

Comment: Yes, it should do the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

This does not call the *copy* constructor in C++11, but the move constructor, which is ok:

- `std::ifstream` is movable in C++11
- `IO` will therefore have a valid compiler generated move-constructor
- since you did not declare a copy-constructor or move-constructor for `Foo`, it will have a valid compiler generated move.constructor as well.
- The return statement in `Foo::NamedConstructor` will call `Foo`'s move-constructor, not the copy-constructor

However, your test code (with the `#ifdef` commented out) does not yet compile on gcc 4.8, because it wants to use the deleted `std::ifstream(std::ifstream&)`. This is due to the not yet fully implemented standard library in gcc (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14640704/1838266)).

Comment: Thanks for checking this out, but if you comment in the `#define NEXT_LINE_CAUSES_CC_OF_IO`, the build will fail.

Comment: Sorry, that one slipped me. I looked into it and edited my answer.